# Android - Rotate a part of an Image

Tags: android, image-processing, imageview

I basically need to rotate 90 degres a small part of an `ImageView` (e.g):

[image: example]

In the Image above, I'd like to rotate the 4 so it displays correctly. Only the 4, the rest should remain vertical as it is.

Is there a way I can achieve it?

By Implementing the method suggested by MikeM. I'm getting the following result.

[image: result]

As you can see there are two major things I need to fix:

1. The rotated square is working, although in the wring position. How do I found out the exact coordinates of the `4`
2. The background of the image, has been changed to black. It used to be transparent

Comment: is it all one image or is the 4 a separate image?

Comment: If that is all a single image, it'd probably be easier to just draw over it.

Comment: @chornge No, it is all one image.

Comment: @MikeM. I would need to draw a white square on top of the 4 and drawing it again on top but rotated. Sounds fine, is it possible?

Comment: Sure, but I think I might not get what the actual question is. Do you have some way of knowing exactly where the 4 is in that image? Or are you also asking how to determine that, as well?

Comment: @MikeM. No as of now, but since the images are all the same, it would be always in the same spot. maybe I could find it out using photoshop and hard code it that way. I think it should work

Comment: @MikeM. I will definitely try that. Thanks

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for the great help you are providing. What do you mean with rotating? is there a way I could "extract" the 4 and rotate it? It would be perfect. Also, can I do the bitmap conversion if the image is imported as a drawable?

Comment: Yeah, I just meant what you had in mind originally. Off the top of my head, get your `Bitmap`, create a second `Bitmap` from that that's just the number, with one of the `Bitmap#createBitmap()` methods that takes a source `Bitmap`, rotate that second `Bitmap`, and use a `Canvas` to draw it back to the first. Actually, not too involved, now that I write it out. I think one of the `createBitmap()` methods even takes a `Matrix`, so you could do that in one step. I'd have to check on that later, though.

Comment: @MikeM. Will this process slow down my app too much? considering I'll have to apply it to 1300 Images (that's right :) )

Comment: That's _craaaazy!_ Seriously, though, I was just checking on that `createBitmap()` method I mentioned earlier, and had a thought about one of your earlier comments. You said the image is imported as a drawable? How exactly do you mean? Did you just mean it's in your `drawable/` folder? Or is this some sort of custom `Drawable` Java class? As for the 1300 images, can you do this ahead of time, somehow? Or does it have to be done at runtime?

Comment: Yeah I know it's kind crazy, but still... No I mean that it's a `webp` within my `drawable` folder, not a java, nor xml class. I probably could find a way to do it in advance, although it still depends on how much time it takes

Comment: Well, it would be much better, performance-wise, if you could do it ahead of time. If not, I just threw together a quick method to test what I've been telling you, so you can see if it's quick enough for your needs. Have a look [at this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yCxiylEdYkbkFKLU0xSW03VDg/view?usp=drivesdk). The first parameter is the `R.drawable` you want to load, second and third are the (x, y) of the top-left of the bit to rotate, and fourth and fifth are the width and height. I'm on an xxhdpi screen, and with the image you posted, I was using values of (..., 1155, 165, 120, 120).

Comment: You'll have to adjust those values if you're on a different density screen, and if that image isn't actual size. It was just a quick and dirty test, but it's easy enough to alter to take real pixel values, and adjust for density programmatically.

Comment: This is great thanks, I will try this out. Post it as an answer too so I can upvote it

Comment: @MikeM. I tried your method and I'm getting this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()`. I suspect that the image here in the post has been stretched someway the original is `422 x 582`, here is a link for you to download the image to test it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_V7i1WXoR-8WUh6OVlqRVRWOUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to adjust those values I gave. If you happen to be running on an xxhdpi screen, then you can just drop the x to probably around 1140, for to test. If you're on something different, you'll have to check the width and height of the `Bitmap` loaded by the `BitmapFactory`, and kinda figure it from that. When you get the real pixel coordinates, you can multiply those by `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density` to get the adjusted values.

Comment: I should've mentioned, the values I gave are by a factor of 3. Divide, then multiply by whatever your `density` is.

Comment: @MikeM. I'm sorry, I only had the chance now to come back to this project. Your method seems to work great and it's exactly what I need. I've updated the question with two minor issues I need to fix. Please have a look at the question when you got time.

Comment: No problem. I haven't really gotten a chance to get to it properly yet myself. 1.) I thought you were going to get those coordinates from Photoshop. If you do that, we can figure how to adjust those correctly for the loaded image. (I have follow-up questions on that, if so.) If instead you want to do that on the fly with some sort of image processing, that's going to be even slower, and I would likely have to bow out, 'cause, honestly, at that point, it'd be easier to write a script to alter all these images on your dev machine before packing them.

Comment: 2.) Are you sure the `View` background isn't black there? Or are you possibly drawing the results onto another blank `Bitmap` somehow? The `BitmapFactory` load in that example snippet wouldn't change the transparent background, and after that, we're just taking a clip, which itself has a transparent background, and drawing it back.

Comment: Oh ok, I will do it with photoshop, only have to figure out how to do it. With image processing would be impossible to do at runtime I think. As for 2), I'll double check the related xml and let you know

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how you're getting a black background. [Here's what I'm getting](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yCxiylEdYkdHlGeFk3dGdpUVU/view?usp=drivesdk) when I use [this refactored method, with the values shown in the example usage](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yCxiylEdYkN2hPdW9iZ3NIak0/view?usp=drivesdk). That's with the image in the `drawable-nodpi/` folder, so it doesn't scale, and so I could get at least approximate real coordinates for now. Note that I changed the parameters from (x, y, width, height), to (left, top, right, bottom), to make the calculations simpler.

Comment: That one's safer, too, since it trims the clip bounds to the image bounds, so you shouldn't get that `IllegalArgumentException` anymore, even if the passed values are out of bounds. Eventually, I'd say you'll wanna find a nice square(ish) region that will cover all the possible numbers there. I can't really do that right now, 'cause I'm not sure what all the possible numbers are (e.g., 2 digits, 3 digits, more?), and my workstation is down, atm, so I'm doing this all on a phone.

Comment: That's great, having the images in the `no-dpi` folder would be perfect. I only have them in `xxhdpi` folder cause I cannot afford to have 1300 images all scaled per dpi. So I'll move them to `no-dpi`, and retry. I'm still having the issue with the black background, but it's I think, because I'm inflating the View using `picasso` and a `getImageUri()` method.

Comment: @MikeM. in your class I'm getting an error on `clip.intersect(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());` saying that the `result of intersect isn't used`, plus I cannot call the loadBitmapMethod from the other class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157179/discussion-between-mike-m-and-daniele).

Comment: I left some new notes regarding that Picasso customization in the chat room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know, or can figure, the coordinates and dimensions of the region you'd like to rotate, then the process is relatively straightforward.

1. Load the image as a mutable `Bitmap`.
2. Create a second, rotated `Bitmap` of the desired region from the original.
3. Create a `Canvas` on the original `Bitmap`.
4. Clear the clipped area, if necessary.
5. Draw the rotated region back onto the original.

In the following example, it's assumed that the region's coordinates (`x`, `y`) and dimensions (`width`, `height`) are already known.

```
// Options necessary to create a mutable Bitmap from the decode
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable = true;

// Load the Bitmap, here from a resource drawable
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId, options);

// Create a Matrix for 90° counterclockwise rotation
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(-90);

// Create a rotated Bitmap from the desired region of the original
Bitmap region = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, x, y, width, height, matrix, false);

// Create our Canvas on the original Bitmap
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

// Create a Paint to clear the clipped region to transparent
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

// Clear the region
canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + width, y + height, paint);

// Draw the rotated Bitmap back to the original,
// concentric with the region's original coordinates
canvas.drawBitmap(region, x + width / 2f - height / 2f, y + height / 2f - width / 2f, null);

// Cleanup the secondary Bitmap
region.recycle();

// The resulting image is in bmp
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

---

To address the concerns in the edit:

1. The rotated region's figures in the original example were based on the image with the long axis vertical. The image in the edit had been rotated to vertical *after* that region had been modified.
2. The black background was due to having inserted the resulting image into `MediaStore`, which saves images in the JPEG format, which does not support transparency.

Comment: Thanks again for the great help you provided.